# SQL Query to get rows that have 3 unique values in column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, having-clause

Blanking out on how to get this data:

I have a table like this:

```
====================
ID     |    Source
====================
1      | google
1      | fb
1      | linkedIn
1      | linkedIn
3      | linkedIn
3      | fb
```

I want to return all the Ids that have 3 sources.

So in the above table, I want the result set to contain only id 1 since it was hit across 3 sources.

Database is mysql 5.7 so anything functions on 8.0 only won't work.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have no primary key. Fix that, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
select id 
from mytable 
group by id 
having count(distinct source) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this and see if that is helpful. It should return only IDs that have exactly 3 unique sources.

```
SELECT ytn.id, COUNT(DISTINCT ytn.source) AS unique_sources
FROM `your_table_name` ytn
GROUP BY ytn.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ytn.source) = 3;
```